# Can I add controls for playback speed and subtitles in the mobile Youtube iFrame?

Tags: video, iframe, youtube, jplayer

Is it possible to add controls into mobile version of YouTube iFrame player?
With controls I mean being able to change the speed and quality of the video, or turn on the subtitles.